# Fill / Shade a chart above a specific Y value in PlotlyJS

Tags: javascript, plotly, stacked-area-chart

I would like to fill until a specific Y value in PlotlyJS. This is as far as I got from the PlotlyJS docs: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wv8hco83/1/)

```
{
  "x": [
    "2016-01-31T00:03:57.000Z",
    "2016-02-12T04:35:26.000Z"
  ],
  "y": [
    100,
    100
  ],
  "fill": "tonexty",
  "fillcolor": "#8adcb3"
}
```

In the documentation, there seems to be two options:

1. `tonexty` - Fills as below. The problem is 'tonexty' is a bit limiting - The use case is 'filling until the line', so shading ONLY above 110. Example:

[image]

2. `tozeroy` - Fills till zero:

[image]

Also, do you need to introduce a new trace in order to create a fill?

This means that [if I have a chart as follows (with only one trace but a threshold line as a shape)](https://jsfiddle.net/de15yseh/): I need to introduce another trace *just to create a fill*. Maybe there's something I missed in the docs, or this is the wrong approach altogether. 
[image]

So, how do you fill an area in a trace above a specific Y value in PlotlyJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution is to use multiple traces.
Split all your traces between ones which are above 0 and ones which are not.
When you are done you can fill them (or not) with the 'tozeroy' value.

The [following jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6nag4Lt/1/) shows a working example.

The code is as following :

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
```

JS:

```
var data = [
  {
    x: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    y: [1, 3, 6, 0],
    fill: 'tozeroy',
    fillcolor: '#8adcb3'
  },
  {
    x: ['D', 'F', 'G', 'I'],
    y: [0, -3, -2, 0],
    fill: 'toself'
  },
   {
    x: ['I', 'J', 'K'],
    y: [0, 5, 7],
    fill: 'tozeroy',
    fillcolor: '#0adcb3'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

The result looks as following :
[image: Result plot]

Comment: [Don't cross the streams](http://quotegeek.com/quotes-from-movies/ghostbusters/206/) More seriously, actually because I was just playing with the plotly lib I can't give you a better solution. I'm curious though how this could be achieved with a more elegant solution.

Comment: It's a pretty good solution. I didn't come up with some more elegant either. You could use legendgroup to make the legend prettier but that's it.

Comment: But more critical: The question was 'above a specific Y-value'. I don't think this will work with your solution or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution exploiting Plotly's `fill: "toself"`. The idea is to create a closed line trace which encloses the area above the threshold and the markers of the main line. Works for threshold values above zero and for numerical x-values.

[image]
The helper traces have their legend hidden and are grouped with the main trace, thereby preventing ugly artifacts when toggling the legend.

The function checks for each x-y-pair if the y-value is above the threshold, if yes

- check if there is already a segment above the threshold and use this one OR create a new sgement
- the segement starts from the y-value of the threshold and the intermediate x-value from the point above the threshold and the one before.
- each segment is terminated with an y-value which is equal to the threshol and the x-value which the mean of the last point in the segment and the next one

The function itself can be surely written in a nicer way but it's just a proof-of-concept.

```js
function dataToTraces(data, threshold) {

  var fillers = [];

  var emptyFiller = {
    x: [],
    y: [],
    fill: "toself",
    mode: "lines",
    line: {
      width: 0
    },
    opacity: 0.5,
    fillcolor: "#8adcb3",
    showlegend: false,
    legendgroup: "main"
  }
  
  fillers.push(emptyFiller);

  for (var i = 0; i < data.y.length; i += 1) {
    if (data.y[i] >= threshold) {
      if (i !== 0 && data.y[i - 1] < threshold) {
        fillers[fillers.length - 1].x.push(data.x[i - 1] + (threshold - data.y[i - 1]) / (data.y[i] - data.y[i - 1]));
        fillers[fillers.length - 1].y.push(threshold);
      }
      fillers[fillers.length - 1].x.push(data.x[i]);
      fillers[fillers.length - 1].y.push(data.y[i]);
    } else if (fillers[fillers.length - 1].x.length > 0) {
      if (i !== 0 && data.y[i - 1] !== threshold) {
        fillers[fillers.length - 1].x.push(data.x[i - 1] + (threshold - data.y[i - 1]) / (data.y[i] - data.y[i - 1]));
        fillers[fillers.length - 1].y.push(threshold);
      }
      fillers.push(emptyFiller);
    }
  }
  return fillers;
}

var data = [{
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  y: [1, 3, 6, 2, -1, 5, 1, 3, 0],
  name: "main",
  legendgroup: "main"
}];
var fillers = dataToTraces(data[0], 2);

Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", data.concat(fillers));
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but could you explain what you are doing in a little more detail?

Comment: @user3886058 I added some explanation, hope it is clearer now